# How can I avoid typing the password again when I select a new remote kernel?

Tags: remote-access

From the menu "Evaluation" -> "Kernel Configuration Options...", I can setup a new remote kernel, but I find it too much trouble to type the password again and again when I select a new remote kernel to run. So I want to ask how to modify the "Shell command to launch kernel" of the "Advanced Options" (add the password to it) to avoid it.